# MEDIAN IF with multiple arguments

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, median

```
=MEDIAN(IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (W)";IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (S)";
  IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (F)";Platform!AE$2:AE$821))))
```

Can someone please correct this formula? I want to find the Median of the data in column AE2:AE821, but only for the values with the text specified in the IFs functions. I get #NUM! back, thanks

Comment: use AGGREGATE function instead of median to set condition and neglect errors

Comment: @AlyAbdelaal AGGREGATE with MEDIAN does not allow arrays, and must be a range.  So, one cannot put the conditions in.

Answer (score 3):

By putting the consecutive IFs in the TRUE portion it is acting like `AND`.  R cannot be both `"Unit (S)"` and `"Unit (F)"` so put them in the FALSE postition:

```
=MEDIAN(
    IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (W)",Platform!AE$2:AE$821,
    IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (S)",Platform!AE$2:AE$821,
    IF(Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (F)",Platform!AE$2:AE$821))))
```

Now it will be `OR`

It can also be shortened using `*` for `AND` and `+` for `OR`:

```
=MEDIAN(
    IF((Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (W)")+
    (Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (S)")+
    (Platform!R$2:R$821="Unit (F)"), 
     Platform!AE$2:AE$821))
```

Note in my Excel I use `,` instead of `;`, so you may need to change all the `,` to `;`